# Replacing characters in a String

Tags: java, string, replace, character, jcreator

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class KBstrings1
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1= scan.nextLine();
        int num=0;

        for(int i=0; i<s1.length();i++)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i)=='a'){
             num++;}
             i++;
        }

        if(num>3)
        {
            System.out.println(s1.replace('a','@')); 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(s1.replace('a','#'));
        }

    }

}
```

I want to create a program that accepts user input of a sentence and replaces all the 'a' characters with '#' if there are 3 or less instances of 'a', and replace 'a' with '@' if there are more than 3 instances. I tried using the sentence "Computer science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes." but my output replaced the 'a' with '#' when it should've replaced it with '@'. I do all my code in JCreator.

Comment: Because you increment i in the loop twice thus it skips over some. Get rid of i++

Comment: when u are already changing the value of 'i' in for-statement, there is no need of doing it again later

Answer (score 3):

You are incrementing i twice.

`for(int i=0; i<s1.length();i++)`

and

`i++;`